# How to use cyrillic file names with Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I get the user file uploaded and save it to Google Cloud Storage:

```
class MyHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        my_file = self.request.POST['agreement']
        default_bucket = app_identity.get_default_gcs_bucket_name()
        gcs_filename = '/%s/%s' % (default_bucket, my_file.filename)
        with gcs.open(gcs_filename, 'w', content_type=my_file.type) as f:
            f.write(my_file.value)
```

which works fine with latin names. But if user uploads file with Cyrillic characters, I get the following error:

```
u'\u0410'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1511, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1077, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 547, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~myappid/1.385593846880232980/myapp.py", line 307, in post
    with gcs.open(gcs_filename, 'w', content_type=my_file.type) as f:
  File "libs/cloudstorage/cloudstorage_api.py", line 91, in open
    filename = api_utils._quote_filename(filename)
  File "libs/cloudstorage/api_utils.py", line 94, in _quote_filename
    return urllib.quote(filename)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 1263, in quote
    return ''.join(map(quoter, s))
KeyError: u'\u0410'
```

How should I fix that?

Upd. I've tried to apply `urllib.quote()` to `my_file.filename`, it works almost OK, but GCS files are stored with non-readable names like `%25D1%2581%25D0%25BA%25D1%2580%25D0%25B8%25D0%25BD%25D1%2588%25D0%25BE%25D1%2582`.

Comment: I don't know if this will fix your problem but you need to make a `gcs_filename` a unicode string like this: `gcs_filename = u'/%s/%s' % (default_bucket, my_file.filename)`.  You should also check if `file.filename` is unicode or some other encoding (e.g., utf8).

Comment: @Kekito, thanks, but it didn't help. I also tried to use `my_file.filename.encode('utf-8')`, it doesn't work also.